# Black window when launching Spotify

Tags: graphics, kubuntu, opengl, spotify, gnutls

So the client was working without any problems. Next day, I turn on my computer this error :

> [1014/192432.737169:ERROR:buffer_manager.cc(488)] [.DisplayCompositor]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glBufferData: <- error from previous GL command

The day before, I just installed Spicetify to customize a bit my client. Asked for this problem, the developer said that it wasn't linked to Spicetify.

Also tried *spotify --disable-gpu*, nothing changed.

*spotify --show-console* output: https://gist.github.com/Funeoz/61cd1ddd6b44ce05691cfc499187d195

- Lenovo Ideapad 330
- Ryzen 7 2700U - Vega 10 Graphics
- Kubuntu 19.10
- Kernel : 5.0.0-32-generic
- libcurl3-gnutls 7.65.3-1ubuntu3
- libgnutls30 3.6.9-5ubuntu1
- OpenGL version string: 4.5 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 19.2.1
- Spotify version 1.1.10.546.ge08ef575

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been noticing this as well ever since I installed spicetify. I'm also at a loss as to what's causing it, but as a workaround, I've found that I'm able to force it to load by running `sudo spicetify apply` but this is a bit inconvenient to do every time you launch the client.

My `spotify -show-console` [output](http://[https://pastebin.com/6VDUptg3][1]).

- HP Zbook 14u g4
- Linux Mint Cinnamon 19.3
- Kernel v. 5.3.0-40-generic
  liburl3-gnutls v. 7.58.0-2ubuntu3.8
- libgnutls30 v. 3.5.18-1ubuntu1.3
- Spotify v. 1.1.10.546.ge08ef575